# How do I use MvxImageView.DefaultImagePath?

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I have successfully used `MvxImageView` with `ImageUrl`, but how can I set a drawable icon as a default for those users which don't have a profilepicture (that is, where ProfileThumbnailImageUrl is empty)?

```
<MvxImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    local:MvxBind="ImageUrl ProfileThumbnailImageUrl"
    DefaultImagePath="@drawable/ic_action_user"/>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If this view is just being used once (e.g. not reused in a list) then you can just use `android:src` for your default image.

If you need to use DefaultImagePath then you can do this in a binding:

```
 local:MvxBind="ImageUrl ProfileThumbnailImageUrl; DefaultImagePath DefaultImageUrl"
```

where `DefaultImageUrl` is a drawable accessed as `res:name` - e.g. `res:ic_action_user`, a file path (saved using the File plugin), or an http url

You should also be able to do this as a string literal:

```
 local:MvxBind="ImageUrl ProfileThumbnailImageUrl; DefaultImagePath 'res:ic_action_user'"
```

Comment: local:MvxBind="ImageUrl ProfileThumbnailImageUrl; DefaultImagePath 'res:ic_action_user'" - Worked perfectly :)

Comment: DefaultImagePath causes huge memory issues now on lollipop devices. Any update on that?